# Ruby on Rails and PostgreSQL scaling and load balancing (hardware and setup recommendations)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, cloud, scalability

**What we want:**

I am looking for hardware, ruby version, and postgresql replication method recommendations for scaling a ruby on rails application that currently sits on 1 server.

**What we use it for:**

The company I work for currently has 1 server that handles the database and our ruby on rails application. Our application takes in GPS and other data from many different locations(mobile devices etc) at a rate of about every 5 seconds. After extensive testing we are ready to deploy it but want to prepare for several hundred/few thousand devices sending data to the server. As far as user interaction we have reports etc. available based on posted data.

I am currently leaning towards postgresql master-master replication and jruby, using separate servers for postgresql and ruby.

I know this has been asked a lot but I figured I should take all research paths possible. I plan on documenting the entire process to share with others so any input you can provide would be great.